# Matching Simple IP addresses in YARA using Hexadecimal Strings

Tags: hex, payara, yara

I am trying to write YARA rules to match simple IP Addresses (eg: 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.1). I understand that I can do it using Regular Expressions based on this open-source Github [example](https://github.com/Yara-Rules/rules/blob/master/utils/ip.yar).

However, YARA performance guidelines recommends us to avoid Regular Expressions whenever possible and use Hexadecimal Jumps/Wildcard matching instead, as stated in this [Github Readme](https://gist.github.com/Neo23x0/e3d4e316d7441d9143c7). I am using it on a large number of examples so I was keeping performance in mind.

I was wondering, does YARA need to get the IP in a hex format, or can I directly match it in the normal IP format (`x.x.x.x`)?

I was trying something like:

```
rule url_localhost
{
    strings:
        $hex_test = { [1-3] 2E [1-3] 2E [1-3] 2E [1-3] ?? ?? }
    condition:
        any of them
}
```

My logic was something like 3 numbers to start, then a dot (2E in ASCII), and repeating the same, and having wildcards in the end for a potential 'path' in the IP address (eg: `127.0.0.1/p`)

It does not seem to directly work. Is this kind of use-case possible, or is Regex the only way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, but it seems you cannot start or end your hex string with a jump ([]).

I got this to work:

```
rule url_localhost{
    strings:
        $hex_test = { ?? [0-2] 2E [1-3] 2E [1-3] 2E }
    condition:
        $hex_test
    }
```

However, I still get a warning that the rule is slowing down the scan.
I have not done any testing of this method vs. regex, but I would think they are doing pretty much the same under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed it's strange that we can't end or start with a jump, I ended up using something similar in my application.